# load up an htaccess file thats in another directory not in the DocumentRoot

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to apply htaccess rules that are located in another directory.

for example

```
/folder
--|__ .htaccess
--|__ /htdocs
--------|__ index.php
```

the DocumentRoot is htdocs, while the htaccess file is located outside of that.

Can I access that htaccess file?

Comment: I misread and didn't notice that your htaccess file is directly above the htdocs directory. In that case, rules defined in it *do* apply to the subdirectory. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: `.htaccess`  rules apply to subdirectories too, so yes, you can place the file one level above `htdocs`. The rules in it will apply.

Comment: well only if you FTP in to the account, but through PHP it is outside of the DocumentRoot. A symlink might work, would I just symlink a dummy htaccess file to the real one that is outside of that directory?

Comment: just to clarify, my `<Virtual Directory>` says that the DocumentRoot is `/folder/htdocs` even if i place the htaccess file one folder above `htdocs` they will still apply?

Comment: hmm, i placed the htaccess one directory above but the rules are being ignored